# How to use Relay Modern (babel-plugin-relay and relay-compiler) with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, babeljs, relayjs, relay

When using TypeScript, babel-plugin-relay and relay-compiler are not parsing our graphql calls.  Our TS-generated JS files look like this, targeting ES2015:

`var mutation = compat_1.graphql(_templateObject2);`

And our output from relay-compiler looks like this, indicating that no files were parsed:

`Parsed default in 0.05s
Writing default
Writer time: 0.05s [0.05s compiling, 0.00s generating, 0.00s extra]
Unchanged: 0 files
Written default in 0.07s`

How can we get relay-compiler and babel-plugin-relay to operate properly on these files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the plugin and the compiler need bare graphql calls to work properly.  If the graphql call takes an object (as the above takes `_templateObject2`) or is called on another object (as it's called on `compat_1` above), neither tool will work.

To fix, we're just using an old-style `require` statement so that the TS transpiler outputs plain `graphql` calls:

`const { commitMutation, graphql } = require('react-relay/compat');`

Works perfectly.